# What just happened to SO's homepage?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, homepage

This is just... wrong. Chrome latest, just started now.

It only seems to be happening on SO, I checked several other SE sites.

[image]

Comment: What Version?. No repro here

Comment: That looks like userscript gone wrong.

Comment: @TravisJ Not using any custom userscripts, version 31.0.1650.63

Comment: @GenericHolidayName I use the same version but no repro. Check again

Comment: I am on Version 31.0.1650.63 m. Don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Perhaps the mobile link shouldn't be shown to desktop users.

Comment: @TravisJ, how can you know for sure that the user is viewing it on a Desktop ?

Comment: @Travis I don't like sites that prevent me from doing something thats technicaly available just because they think I shouldn't.  Mobile browsers had to get a whole setting of "pretend to be a desktop" because of that sort of thing

Comment: @Habib - Feature detection.

Comment: @RichardTingle - I would blame that more on Safari's fail mobile browser than on sites specifically. When the iPhone first came out it rendered a lot of pages.. well, horribly. It is better now, and android does a really good job of it. Either way, it is just noise. I doubt any desktop users want to view the page in the mobile setting. It is essentially a link for less features, not more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You accidentally switched to the mobile site. Click the "full site" link at the bottom to revert.

Comment: Well ain't that something. Typical idiot user. No idea how I *accidentally* clicked a footer link, but seems I did.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you're on mobile; that's what the mobile browser looks like on iPhone. Go back to the full site by going to the bottom and clicking 'full site'